# Best way to invest ~10k euros in Europe

Tags: investing, savings, europe, passive-income, austria

newbie here. I'd like to know what are the best ways to invest ~10k euros here in Europe. I don't have any debt and I am able to save 1k euros every month moving forward. I can't buy property yet, because I can't get a loan in my home country (not employed there) and can't get a loan in my current country because I ain't a citizen. I was looking at savings accounts but earnings are really low. 0.4% a year isn't that fun.

If you folks could point me in the right direction so that I could learn more, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I've heard that in Germany there are vending machines that sell gold. The advantage of having a bar of gold is that a banker can't hit a delete key and take it away (unless you put the gold inside a bank). Ask people in Cyprus about that.

Comment: I'm just asking for good articles where I could learn more about investing such amount of money. Go be funny someplace else.

Comment: That's against the rules of the site because in that case the question is subjective and has no concrete answer. Read the help before posting.

Comment: @yoozer8 Thanks, yes and no... As with all other answers on this site, it's geared towards Americans and 401k, stuff that we in EU don't have, nor do we care about retirement funds. But there is some good advice about creating emergency funds and some books recommendation. Thanks for trying to actually fulfill the role of the site, unlike Five Bagger, who was useless.